# Random variable $Y$ has moment generating function $M_Y(t)=(0.7+0.3e^t)^4 $ let $W=2Y-4$ what is the moment generating function of $W$

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Random variable $Y$ has moment generating function $$M_Y(t)=(0.7+0.3e^t)^4$$ Let $W=2Y-4$ what is the moment generating function of $W$?

i don't understand how $W$ interact with the $M_Y(t)$ .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$
M_W(t) = E[e^{tW}] = E[e^{2tY - 4t}] = E[e^{2tY}e^{-4t}] = e^{-4t}E[e^{2tY}]
$$

Comment: whats the relation between $$M_Y(t)=(0.7+0.3e^t)^4 to this though ?

Comment: @cindy and $M_Y(t)=E[e^{tY}]$

Comment: @cindy Like Caran-d'Ache said, $M_Y(t)=E[e^{tY}]$. In that means that $E[e^{2tY}] = M_Y(2t)$.